# Unable to display elements stored in the arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm learning arraylist in Java but I have met a challenge I'm unable to overcome.
To get to the point, I am unable to display the elements I stored into the arraylist.
I am able to call a method from the constructor file but I am unable to display them when I store them into the arraylist.

Below is my source code for all 3 files:

This is my main java file:

```
package test;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Basket basket = new Basket();
        addDVD();
        viewBasket();
        basket.printDetails();
        basket.printDetails1();
    }
    
    public static void addDVD() {
        Basket basket = new Basket();
        
        DVD gmc = new DVD("God Must be Crazy", "Comedy", "Director", 1990, 12.99);
        DVD interstellar = new DVD("Interstellar", "Sci-Fi", "Director2", 2016, 16.99);
        
        basket.addDVD(gmc);
        basket.addDVD(interstellar);
    }   
    
    public static void viewBasket() {
        DVD gmc = new DVD("God Must be Crazy", "Comedy", "Director", 1990, 12.99);
        DVD interstellar = new DVD("Interstellar", "Sci-Fi", "Director2", 2016, 16.99);
        
        gmc.printDetails();
        interstellar.printDetails();
    }
}
```

This is the encapsulation and constructor file:

```
package test;

public class DVD {
    private String title;
    private String genre;
    private int year;
    private String director;
    private double price;
    
    public DVD (String title, String genre, String director, int year, double price) {
        setTitle(title);
        setGenre(genre);
        setDirector(director);
        setYear(year);
        setPrice(price);
    }
    
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }
    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    public String getDirector() {
        return director;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public void setGenre(String genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }
    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
    public void setDirector(String director) {
        this.director = director;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    
    public void printDetails() {
        System.out.println(
                "Title: " + getTitle() + "\n" +
                "Price: " + getPrice() + "\n"
                );
    }
    
}
```

and finally, this is the arraylist file I'm trying to make it work:

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Basket {
    List<DVD> DVDlist = new ArrayList<DVD>();
    
    public void addDVD (DVD dvd) {
        DVDlist.add(dvd);
        System.out.println("The dvd details has been stored into the array!");
    }
    
    /*
     * public double totalPrice() { double totalprice = 0; for (DVD dvd:DVDlist) {
     * totalprice = totalprice + dvd.getPrice(); } return totalprice; }
     */
    
    public void printDetails() {
        System.out.println("Displaying details");
        for (DVD dvd:DVDlist) {
            System.out.println("Title: " + dvd.getTitle());
            System.out.println("Price: " + dvd.getPrice());
        }
    }
    public void printDetails1() {
        System.out.println("Displaying Details from list");
        for(int i=0;i<DVDlist.size();i++) {
            System.out.println(DVDlist.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

**Note: There is no error displaying when I debug the code and I have put various print lines to make sure that all functions are working. They are working when I run the code but there is no display for the arraylist method**

Comment: The `basket` in `addDVD` is different from the `basket` in `main` method. The DVDs are not getting in the `basket` from the `main` method. So trying to do `basket.printDetails()` would not give you anything

Comment: @NickDiv so to display the elements stored in the arraylist, I have to call the method "basket.printDetails()" inside the addDVD() ?

Comment: Do not create a new Basket in your Client addDVD method!

Comment: @Jimmy You can do that but you also have other option.. Either make the `basket` from `main` method a class variable and no need to instantiate in `addDVD()` again OR the other option is what you mentioned.

Comment: Can I ask what you mean by "make the basket from main method a class variable and no need to instantiate in addDVD()." ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a new element in the `addDVD` method, so what you are populating with DVD isn't the basket in your main method, but the basket created into `addDVD`.

Try to pass basket as parameter of addDVD

```
package test;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Basket basket = new Basket();
        addDVD(basket);

        // no more needed 
        // viewBasket();

        basket.printDetails();
        basket.printDetails1();
    }
    
    public static void addDVD(Basket basket) {
        // No more needed
        // Basket basket = new Basket();
        
        DVD gmc = new DVD("God Must be Crazy", "Comedy", "Director", 1990, 12.99);
        DVD interstellar = new DVD("Interstellar", "Sci-Fi", "Director2", 2016, 16.99);
        
        basket.addDVD(gmc);
        basket.addDVD(interstellar);
    }   
    
    public static void viewBasket() {
        DVD gmc = new DVD("God Must be Crazy", "Comedy", "Director", 1990, 12.99);
        DVD interstellar = new DVD("Interstellar", "Sci-Fi", "Director2", 2016, 16.99);
        
        gmc.printDetails();
        interstellar.printDetails();
    }
}
```